# Use auto layout to position button near the center

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I'm using auto layout in Xcode and I have some buttons I want to be near the center, but not on it. I know I can use alignment constraints to be exactly in the center, in this menu:
[image]

However, I want to not be exactly in the center, lets say 50 pixels up and to the right. How can I do this? I'm sure it's an easy thing to do, but I can't seem to find anything elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the center of your button to be 50 points up and to the right of the parent view's center you can use a center x alignment constraint and a center y alignment constraint and set the center x alignment constraint's constant to 50 and the center y alignment constraint's constant to -50.

[image: off center by 50 on each axis]
[image]

Comment: This answer is much better than mine. You have my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with size 50 * 50. Then place this view exactly at the center using auto layout.

[image]

Next you need to place your button using `vertical space` and `horizontal space` in order to be aligned to the upper right corner of the view.

[image]

Finally make the view transparent.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, good idea. Surprising that there is not built in way to do this.

Comment: For what reason? Maybe I wasn't clear with my comment, the statement "Surprising that there is not a built in way to do this" was intended to either incite another user into supplying a built in way or to explain why I am waiting to accept your answer. Is that why you sent me the link?